# app_artifact_location when the app is internationalized

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

I'm working with the new [Azure Static Web Apps Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/) product, not to be confused with Azure Web Apps.

My Angular 9 app, which runs fine locally, is all set up for [internationalization,](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) and one effect of the internationalization is that it drops my `index.html` into `app/catfood/dist/en_US` rather than `app/catfood/dist`.

This is leaving me stuck in terms of how to set the `app_artifact_location` value in the workflow file. If I leave it at the default value of `"dist/catfood"` the build gives me this error, which honestly does seem accurate as the `index.html` isn't going to be there:

```
Failed to find a default file in the app artifacts folder (dist/congruence-web). Valid default files: index.html,Index.html.
If your application contains purely static content, please verify that the variable 'app_location' in your workflow file (located in .github/workflows) points to the root of your application.
If your application requires build steps, please validate that a default file exists in the build output directory.
```

But if I change it to the logical `"dist/catfood/en_US"` I get this error:

```
The app build failed to produce artifact folder: 'dist/catfood/en_US'. Please ensure this property is configured correctly in your workflow file.
```

Really not sure what the build system is expecting of me. What should I be using for `app_artifact_location`? Or am I even tweaking the wrong thing here?

Update: When I deliberately turn off i18n in `angular.json`, the `en_US` directory goes away and `index.html` is found in `dist/catfood` and everything works great. So basically the problem is "Why does Azure Static Web Apps not understand localized Angular applications?"

Comment: Could you solve it in the mean time?

Comment: Nah, I gave up on Azure Static Web Apps.